# Can't show Polygon from ReactNativeMaps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, maps, react-native-maps

I can not view the polygon correctly.
I think it's because from my API I receive an array of objects..

This is my code

```
<MapView.Polygon
  coordinates={poligonofinale}
  strokeColor="#000"
  fillColor="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"
  strokeWidth={3}/>
```

My coordinates var is

```
const poligonofinale = this.state.poligono.map(poligono => {
   let test = poligono["poligono"][0]
   return test.coordinates;
});
```

Doing a console.log in poligonofinale i get this

```
Array [
Array [
    Object {
        "latitude": 45.49618557493205,
        "longitude": 12.253101244568825,
    },
    Object {
        "latitude": 45.49635266968306,
        "longitude": 12.252548038959503,
    },
    Object {
        "latitude": 45.496856301073855,
        "longitude": 12.25320216268301,
    },
    Object {
        "latitude": 45.496716939221876,
        "longitude": 12.25351095199585,
    },
],]
```

I think this Double array is wrong so that's why i can't render the polygon.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this lines of code in coordinates..

`<MapView.Polygon 
..
coordinates={poligonofinale[0]}/>`